# Query to find an entry between dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing several records associated to the same entities. Two of the fields are dates - start and end dates of a specific period.

Example:

| ID | Name | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Fred | 2022/01/01 | 2100/12/31 |
| 2 | John | 2018/01/01 | 2021/12/31 |
| 1 | Mark | 2014/03/22 | 2017/12/31 |

The dates and names vary, but the only rule is that there are NO OVERLAPS - it's a succession of people in charge of a unique role, so there is only one record which is valid for any date.

I have a query returning me a date (let's call it $ThatDay) and what I am trying to do is to find a way to find which name it was at that specific date. For example, if the date was July 4th, 2019, the result of the query I am after would be "John"

I have run out of ideas on how to structure a query to help me find it. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: How do you pass $ThatDay? Will it have a date type or a text type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a `SELECT` with `BETWEEN` as `WHERE` clause

The date format of MySQL is yyyy-mm-dd , if you keep that you wil never have problems

> ```
> CREATE TABLE datetab (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `Name` VARCHAR(4),
>   `Start` DATETIME,
>   `End` DATETIME
> );
>
> INSERT INTO datetab
>   (`ID`, `Name`, `Start`, `End`)
> VALUES
>   ('3', 'Fred', '2022/01/01', '2100/12/31'),
>   ('2', 'John', '2018/01/01', '2021/12/31'),
>   ('1', 'Mark', '2014/03/22', '2017/12/31');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `Name` FROM datetab WHERE '2019-07-04' BETWEEN `Start` AND `End`
> ```
>
> ```
> | Name |
> | :--- |
> | John |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3d11c0afdd9d6570c46e146d2d588ce6)*

If ou have a (Sub)- Query with a date as result,you can join it for example

> ```
> SELECT `Name` 
> FROM datetab CROSS JOIN (SELECT '2019-07-04' as mydate FROM dual) t1
> WHERE mydate BETWEEN `Start` AND `End`
> ```
>
> ```
> | Name |
> | :--- |
> | John |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=53c50c73fa9e6e6cde80b72e339ade66)*

Also when the query only return one row and column you can use the subquery like this

> ```
> SELECT `Name` 
> FROM datetab 
> WHERE (SELECT '2019-07-04' as mydate FROM dual) BETWEEN `Start` AND `End`
> ```
>
> ```
> | Name |
> | :--- |
> | John |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b59eeb422e55e92e4e2a653614249be)*

Answer (score 1):

Select where the result of your find-date query is between `start` and `end`:

```sql
select * from mytable
where (<my find date query>)
   between start and end
```